Robot framework script with open browser keyword fails on jenkins with OS Error
OSError: [WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail
can any body let me know how to fix this, and is it possible to use selenium keywords like open browser from jenkins.

What Application? Post an example of the test suite you are using? How do you launch robot in your computer? How you launch on Jenkins?
